# How swift know value of memory is address or actual value that I assigned

Tags: swift, reference, heap-memory, memory-address, value-type

```swift
struct ValueType {
    var member: Int
}

class ReferenceType {
    var member: Int

    init(member: Int) {
        self.member = member
    }
}

var valueTypeObject = ValueType(member: 3)
var referenceTypeObject = ReferenceType(member: 4)

withUnsafePointer(to: &referenceTypeObject) {
    print("referenceTypeObject address: \($0)")
}

withUnsafePointer(to: &valueTypeObject) {
    print("valueTypeObject address: \($0)")
}
```

When executing the above code, the address of each object appears like this.

```swift
valueTypeObject address: 0x0000000100008218
referenceTypeObject address: 0x0000000100008220
```

First, if I view memory of `valueTypeObject` address (`0x0000000100008218`), I can check the `03` value within 64 bits that I actually allocated  (`03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`. Maybe data is stored as little endian.)

[image]

Next, if I view memory of `referenceTypeObject` address (`0x0000000100008220`), I can check `0x000000010172f8b0` is stored in 64bit. (I don't know why right side of `..r.....` is also highlighted, and what it is )

[image]

I know that the `referenceTypeObject` is reference type, so the actual value is in the heap area. So I can guess `0x000000010172f8b0` is an address that stores the actual value that I assigned (in this case, 4.)
But how does Swift know that this is the address that points to heap area instead of `0x000000010172f8b0` value that can be assied by me?

In addition, if I view memory of address `0x000000010172f8b0` where the actual value is stored, there are some 32 bytes values in front of the value that I allocated (in this case, 4). What are those?

[image]

Comment: "But how does Swift know that this is the address that points to heap area" It doesn't and why is this important in the first place? The Swift compiler is just responsible for generating machine code from your source code. It doesn't need to know about which specific addresses point to what.

Comment: I wonder how os can know that they need to access the address `0x000000010172f8b0` to get the value 4 in ReferenceType.
It does not consider `03 00 00 00` at ValueType memory as address (like 0x00000000000000003) to access the value `3`

Comment: Because your computer is running the machine code that the Swift compiler has generated, and the Swift compiler doesn't generate machine code that accesses the address 0x000000000000003. And this is because when generating code, the compiler reads your Swift code, and in the same way as you, understands that  `referenceTypeObject` stores a reference, whereas `valueTypeObject` stores just the value itself, so it generates different code that handles them differently. Does that answer your question? I don't need to explain why the Swift compiler understands Swift code, right?

Comment: Yes, I think my question was a little unclear.

I think I had to ask how Swift Compiler handled the reference type and value type differently when generating the machine code, which makes my computer could decide to read the values in the address of the instance right away or know and move to that address. (For example, is there a any specific command in SIL?)

Is my question more clear now?

Comment: (In fact, when I assigned a long value to `String`,  which is a a value type, I checked that the address of the instance had a strange value, not the one I assigned (I don't know if it's a heap address). So technically speaking, just because it's a value type, it doesn't seem like the compiler is doing the same thing to read the values of the address right away.)